# AngularJS Module is not loading properly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, module

The AngularJS application that I'm working on runs on any server without giving any issues. However the same app throws an error when we configure it to be redirected through Siteminder authentication. Please refer the screenshot. Thanks in advance.

[image: Console log]

Comment: Please let me know if my answer solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Concidering the little amount of information you provide it's hard to help you.

You must have a 404 error on one of your JS scripts.

Because :

- You use a relative path that is broken by Siteminder
- Siteminder force HTTPS and you access a script by http (`script src="http://"`)

If it doesn't solve your problem I advise you to edit your question with more info